# Rails: Click on results in Algolia search auto-completion

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, search, algolia

I installed Algolia to implement an efficient for my rails app:
The algolia search bar is well configured because I can find what I am looking for in my db.
Users can find pins using the search bar with auto-completion in the bar.

But I would like to allow them on the results to go on the pin page.

```
<!-- algolia search -->


 <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Search for users by name..." id="user-search" spellcheck="false" />

<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Typahead.js is used to display the auto-completion menu -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.10.4/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- Hogan.js is used to render the hits using Mustache.js templating -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/hogan.js/3.0.0/hogan.common.js"></script>
<!-- Algolia -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/algoliasearch/latest/algoliasearch.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Replace the following values by your ApplicationID and ApiKey.
    var algolia = new AlgoliaSearch('MYAPPID', 'MYAPPPW');
    // replace YourIndexName by the name of the index you want to query.
    var index = algolia.initIndex('Pin');

    // Mustache templating by Hogan.js (http://mustache.github.io/)
    var template = Hogan.compile('<div class="hit">' +
      '<div class="name">' +
        '{{{ _highlightResult.description.value }}} ' +
        '({{{ _highlightResult.details.value }}})' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>');

    // typeahead.js initialization
    $('#user-search').typeahead(null, {
      source: index.ttAdapter({ hitsPerPage: 5 }),
      displayKey: 'email',
      templates: {
        suggestion: function(hit) {
          // select matching attributes only
          hit.matchingAttributes = [];
          for (var attribute in hit._highlightResult) {
            if (attribute === 'name' || attribute == 'company') {
              // already handled by the template
              continue;
            }
            // all others attributes that are matching should be added in the matchingAttributes array
            // so we can display them in the dropdown menu. Non-matching attributes are skipped.
            if (hit._highlightResult[attribute].matchLevel !== 'none') {
              hit.matchingAttributes.push({ attribute: attribute, value: hit._highlightResult[attribute].value });
            }
          }

          // render the hit using Hogan.js
          return template.render(hit);
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>


<!-- /algolia search -->
```

I want the user to be redirected onto the pin show view when clicking on a result.

So I don't know how to render this link into the Hogan link as the adress for my pin is for example: myapp.com/pins/2 for pin 2

**SOLUTION**: 
add the link into the hoogan template, where slug is for me the modified URL with friendly_id gem.

```
// Mustache templating by Hogan.js (http://mustache.github.io/)
var template = Hogan.compile('<div class="hit">' +
'<a href="http://myapp.com/pins/{{{slug}}}" class="name">' +
    '{{{ _highlightResult.description.value }}} ' +
    '({{{ _highlightResult.details.value }}})' +
  '</a>' +
  '</div>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the hoogan template to add a link, here is an example using the linkedin link http://jsfiddle.net/bxvnqtan/

```
// Mustache templating by Hogan.js (http://mustache.github.io/)
var template = Hogan.compile('<div class="hit">' +
'<a href="{{{linkedin}}}" class="name">' +
    '{{{ _highlightResult.description.value }}} ' +
    '({{{ _highlightResult.details.value }}})' +
  '</a>' +
  '</div>');
```

Comment: Hey thanks @Shipow - But how Could I redirect to the associated show view of the pin? I'll edit my question with more infos. Thanks btw.

Comment: had the solution just using: '<a href="http://myapp.com/{{{object}}}" class="name">' I updated the answer with the solution.